# PHP: Converting an url variable number to a number

Tags: php, character-encoding, numbers

I'm trying to `send a number` from a page to another on in order to save it on my database, but when I use `number_format` method the number is converted to `0`:

```
<?php
    $_REQUEST["myNumber"]; // the number from the url is 25%2C8 (25,8)
    // why this returns 0? 
    number_format (urlencode($_REQUEST["myNumber"]), 2, ".", "");
?>
```

I thought `urlencode` function was useful to convert url numbers to string numbers, where's my fault?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to use [urldecode](http://php.net/manual/en/function.urldecode.php) function instead of urlencode if you want to decode characters.   And pass ',' as decimal pointer.

So your code should looks like this:

```
number_format (urldecode($_REQUEST["myNumber"]), 2, ",", "");
```

But you need to take to account that variables in $_POST\GET\REQUEST arrays is *already decoded*. Perhaps, your code may be even simpler:

```
number_format ($_REQUEST["myNumber"], 2, ",");
```

Comment: +1 for mentioning that he isusing non-standard (ie. localized) decimal separator

Comment: thanks for help, I'm italian and italian numbers are usually rapresented with "," as decimal separator.

Answer (score 0):

`number_format` expects a number (float, to be exact) as the first argument, and the `'25,8'` won't be recognized as float. You'd need to do something like:

```
str_replace(',','.', $_REQUEST["myNumber"]); // '25,8' --> '25.8'
```

to convert a *single* comma to a string that can be evaluated as decimal number (which can be stored in db).

Running:

```
print number_format('25,8', 2);
```

returns `25.00` which is not `25.80` (which I assume is your desired result).